# Starting a video when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site, Link A and Link B can link to Page X.

I want to start a video automatically on Page X if I come from Link A, but NOT when I come from Link B.

Is there any way I can do this using javascript/jquery?

For Reference: I am using fancy box to start the video.

Comment: Send a parameter along with Link A in the URL, check the URL on page load, if page A, run video, else, nothing.

Comment: post your current code

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet In a situation like this, I'd only see that as a distraction instead of a supplement. The question that the OP is asking can easily help other users who come to this page without any code. Adding code will make it more user-specific and take away from its quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take to this problem.

**Option 1**

*This option was my first proof of concept.*

On your first page:

```
<a href="/newpage#linkA">Link A</a>
<a href="/newpage">Link B</a>
```

And on `/newpage`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if(window.location.hash === "#linkA"){
            // play video
        }
    });
</script>
```

or **Option 2:**

*The first option doesn't account for the fact that the page will not refresh if you use the back button. Using a query string does cause the page to refresh though, thus breeding this solution.*

On your first page:

```
<a href="/newpage?playVideoA=1">Link A</a>
<a href="/newpage">Link B</a>
```

And on `/newpage`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if(window.location.search.substring(1) === "playVideoA=1"){
            // play video
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This does exactly what it needs to but I'm playing around with the off chance that someone would go to "/newpage#linkA" and then go to "/newpage" and then try to go back (with the back button). No matter how many times I click the back button, it just switches between "/newpage#linkA" and "/newpage." Did I miss something?

Comment: Looks like the browser isn't refreshing with the hash when you navigate back. Updated my answer with an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

So essentially you want to detect history. Simply use `document.referrer`.

Something like:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
  if (document.referrer === LINK_A) {
    startVideo();
  }
});
```

should be fine for your purposes.

Comment: Side not: Because the OP is using Javascript, it'd probably be better to use jQ event listeners (for universal support) instead of `addEventListener` which has limited support for IE-based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this. One is to check the value of document.referrer to see what the previous page was. A better way is to have your Page X accept a "autostart_video" HTTP GET parameter. So your link would go to a url like http://mysite.com/pageX?autostart=True . If your page is built dynamically (e.g. if you are using Django) then you can check for that parameter and modify the javsacript accordingly.